# Splitting window vertically (rather than horizontally) when searching in Dired

Tags: dired, window-splitting

My Emacs Dired window is wider than it is tall. After marking some files (say `%m *.cpp`) in Dired and running `M-x dired-do-find-regexp <REGEXP>` (`A`), I find myself in `split-window-below` (ex `split-window-horizontally`). I would like to split vertically (`split-window-right`) instead.

Neither setting

```
(setq split-width-threshold nil)
```

in my `.emacs` nor [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21653/3922) suggestion work.

(Emacs 25.3.1 on macOS)

Comment: I added a second example to a related thread describing how to display a `dired-mode` buffer, or a file at point in a `dired-mode` buffer, in one of four directions (left, right, above, below):  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15118/2287 .  I have not played around with the searching in dired feature, so I don't have a specific example for that feature.  If you are a little handy with Lisp, then perhaps you may enjoy the *first* and/or *second* examples in the above link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function at issue is `pop-to-buffer`, which is called within `xref--show-xref-buffer`.  The variable `xref-show-xrefs-function` is set with the default value of `xref--show-xref-buffer`.  Thus, it is relatively simple to set the variable `xref-show-xrefs-function` to a user-defined function.  The example below replaces `xref--show-xref-buffer` with a new function that calls a custom display-buffer function instead of `pop-to-buffer`.  Over the past few years, there have been a few threads on stackexchange/stackoverflow seeking to modify the default behavior of `pop-to-buffer`, and there are a variety of approaches such as customizing the `display-buffer-alist`, or installing additional libraries designed to trump the default behavior of displaying buffers in favor of a user-defined approach, or changing the `split-window-preferred-function` (i.e., `split-window-sensibly`) to something else, and the list of other options/ideas goes on ....  Inasmuch as the O.P. has indicated previously adjusting the variable `split-width-threshold`, @lawlist did not invest any time attempting to customize that variable and/or the companion variable for splitting in the opposite direction (i.e., `split-height-threshold`).

The function `dired-do-find-regexp` is bound in Emacs 25 to the capital letter `A` in `dired-mode`.  The following code will present the user with four options when performing a search at the outset, e.g., display the target buffer left, right, above, or below.  Please feel free to hard-wire it to a particular direction (by passing the optional DIRECTION argument [`'left` | `'right` | `'above` | `'below`] to `my-xref-display-buffer`) if that seems more appealing.  The sky is the limit in terms of customization, e.g., control size of the new window, etc.  However, further customization is beyond the scope of this limited example.

```lisp
(defun my-xref--show-xref-buffer (xrefs alist)
  (let ((xref-alist (xref--analyze xrefs)))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create xref-buffer-name)
      (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
        (erase-buffer)
        (xref--insert-xrefs xref-alist)
        (xref--xref-buffer-mode)
        (my-xref-display-buffer (current-buffer))
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (setq xref--window (assoc-default 'window alist))
        (current-buffer)))))

(defun my-display-buffer (buffer-or-name alist direction &optional size pixelwise)
"BUFFER:  The buffer that will be displayed.
ALIST:  See the doc-string of `display-buffer' for more information.
DIRECTION:  Must use one of these symbols:  'left 'right 'below 'above
SIZE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
PIXELWISE:  See the doc-string for `split-window'.
There are three possibilities:
-  (1) If a window on the frame already displays the target buffer,
then just reuse the same window.
-  (2) If there is already a window in the specified direction in relation
to the selected window, then display the target buffer in said window.
-  (3) If there is no window in the specified direction, then create one
in that direction and display the target buffer in said window."
  (let* ((buffer
           (if (bufferp buffer-or-name)
             buffer-or-name
             (get-buffer buffer-or-name)))
         (window
           (cond
             ((get-buffer-window buffer (selected-frame)))
             ((window-in-direction direction))
             (t
               (split-window (selected-window) size direction pixelwise)))))
    (window--display-buffer buffer window 'window alist display-buffer-mark-dedicated)
    window))

(defun my-xref-display-buffer (buffer &optional direction alist)
"Display an xref results buffer in the desired direction: l/r/a/b."
(interactive)
  (let* ((direction
           (if direction
             direction
             (let ((char (read-char-exclusive (concat
                      "["
                      (propertize "l" 'face '(:foreground "red"))
                      "]"
                      (propertize "eft" 'face '(:foreground "blue"))
                      " | ["
                      (propertize "r" 'face '(:foreground "red"))
                      "]"
                      (propertize "ight" 'face '(:foreground "blue"))
                      " | ["
                      (propertize "a" 'face '(:foreground "red"))
                      "]"
                      (propertize "bove" 'face '(:foreground "blue"))
                      " | ["
                      (propertize "b" 'face '(:foreground "red"))
                      "]"
                      (propertize "elow" 'face '(:foreground "blue"))))))
                (cond
                  ((eq char ?l)
                    'left)
                  ((eq char ?r)
                    'right)
                  ((eq char ?a)
                    'above)
                  ((eq char ?b)
                    'below)
                  ;;; FIXME:  @lawlist may add a loop similar to `org-capture'
                  ;;; whereby a new `read-char-exclusive' will be initiated if
                  ;;; a user did not initially choose a valid option (l/r/a/b).
                  (t
                    (let ((debug-on-quit nil)
                          (msg (concat "my-xref-display-buffer:  "
                                       "You did not select l/r/a/b "
                                       "-- exiting.")))
                      (signal 'quit `(,msg)))))))))
    (select-window (my-display-buffer buffer alist direction))))

(setq xref-show-xrefs-function 'my-xref--show-xref-buffer)
```

Comment: Nice, especially in also handling the unpredictability of above/below and left/right, but an automated solution ("if the aspect ratio is greater than m:1, split vertically; otherwise split horizontally") would be nicer. Would gladly settle for the dired buffer to always be, say, right or below.

Comment: You may be interested in having a look at the built-in function `window-splittable-p` and weave that into your own custom function.   If you run into trouble, you can always open a new question showing what you have tried, etc.